# AWS lib3s C/C++ Library Sample Code / Tutorials

Tags: c, api, callback, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have downloaded and looked over the code for [libs3](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-S3/1648), a library written for C/C++ that interacts with Amazon S3.  This library uses a couple of concepts I am not completely comfortable with, so I am curious as to whether or not people know of any tutorials or sample programs that utilize this library.

Comment: The source code comes with a utility program (s3.c) that is a command line wrapper around the library, and shows how to use all the library calls.

Comment: If this question has been answered, please answer it yourself and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place I have found reasonable examples is by examining the header files for libs3, and by looking through the source code of the s3.c application now included with the library.

Answer (score 2):

Give http://ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/cpp/, a read; there are several examples there.  Additionally, the source code has some good examples such as https://github.com/ceph/libs3/blob/master/src/s3.c#L1396 which is an example of putObject.